# split string into 8 characters piece and reverse the order by two characters

Tags: python-3.x

I have the script that is mostly works but the output format is not what I want.

```
input_string = "A156C673017A85C112345678"
```

Step(1): break  input_string into 8 characters

```
A156C673
017A85C1
12345678
```

Step(2): reverse the characters

```
A156C673 => 73C656A1
017A85C1 => C1857A01
12345678 => 78563412
```

I would like the output to be a single string as follow:

```
output_string=73C656A1C1857A0178563412
```

Can someone please help ?

```
##########Step(1)break string into 32 bits chunk###########
input_string = "A156C673017A85C112345678"#330F2345"
print (f"original string is {input_string}\n")
step=8
for i in range (0,len(input_string),step):
    if i==0:

        string_byte_reverse_rev2(input_string[i:step],output_file,1)
        print (f'string2b is {input_string[i:i+step]}\n')
    else:
        string_byte_reverse_rev2(input_string[i:i+step],output_file,1)
        print (f'string2b is {input_string[i:i+step]}\n')

##########Step(2)Reverse every 2 characters###########

def string_byte_reverse_rev2(string,output_file,label):    
    stringrev=[]
    for i in range (len(string)-1,-1,-2):
        stringrev.append(string[i-1])
        stringrev.append(string[i])
    print(''.join(stringrev))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension for this:

```
def divide(l, n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]

input_string = "A156C673017A85C112345678"
parts = divide(input_string, 8)
stringrev = ''.join(''.join(divide(part, 2)[::-1]) for part in parts)
print(stringrev) # => "73C656A1C1857A0178563412"
```

Comment: output string must be

Comment: #output_string=73C656A1C1857A0178563412

Comment: So you don't want to reverse the characters one by one, but two by two?

Comment: The output must be #output_string=73C656A1C1857A0178563412. reverse by two characters

Answer (score 1):

This is what you were looking for as I understood it.

- Moved string_byte_reverse_rev2 above the main body of code
- Added third step for combining reversed bytes into single string

This isn't far off of what you had, just cleaned some stuff up (didn't want to use a completely different technique than what you were thinking of).

```
#string reversal in pairs
def string_byte_reverse_rev2(string):
    stringrev = ""
    for _ in range (0, len(string), 2):
        stringrev = string[_ + 1] + stringrev
        stringrev = string[_] + stringrev
    # print(stringrev)
    return stringrev

##########Step(1)break string into 32 bits chunk###########
input_string = "A156C673017A85C112345678"
print (f"original string is {input_string}\n")
step = 8

##########Step(2)Reverse every 2 characters###########
for _ in range (0, len(input_string), step):
    string_byte_reverse_rev2(input_string[_ : _ + step])
    # print (f'string2b is {input_string[_ : _ + step]}\n')

##########Step(3)Combine into single reversed string##########
output_string = ""
for _ in range (0, len(input_string), step):
    output_string += string_byte_reverse_rev2(input_string[_ : _ + step])
print("reversed string is",output_string)
```

**Output:**

```
original string is A156C673017A85C112345678

reversed string is 73C656A1C1857A0178563412
```